# WSUS CPU & MEM issue

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wsus, cpu-usage, memory-usage

We have hosted WSUS services on Windows Server 2008 R2. The sqlservr.exe and w3wp.exe is using lot of memory.

But as per observation The physical memory is 50% used but CPU usage is more than 90%.

By this WSUS app crashes all the time when it tries to fetch the packages.

Need your help in solving this issue, Let me know any other information is required.

[image: Cap1]

[image: Cap2]

Comment: Well first off there is not a lot of information here, when did this issues start? Was it after a recent update? Additionally we cant really see most of the task manager output in this photo, just at first glance it looks like you have an IIS process that is chewing up a lot of resources. I would use like process explorer and the event event viewer to trouble shoot this issue, and find out which process in IIS is killing your box.

Comment: This is actually pretty common, but there's a lot of different "fixes".  We spent hours with MS support on the same type of issue tweaking IIS pools, etc. without any great resolution.  I know it's not what you'd like to hear, but in the end we had to migrate to a 2012 R2 server just to resolve this issue.  Didn't matter if there were 2 vCPUs or 8, the issue persisted until we migrated.

Comment: [use WPR/WPA to analyze the cpu usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44137653/1466046). 2008R2 is based on wIn7 code, so use the 1511/15086 SDK